# Scrapy: find strings from a previously defined list in an HTML document

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to use scrapy to take the strings from a predefined list `bacteria_species` and match them string by string with the elements from an HTML document from the website `http://www.microbiologyresearch.org/content/journal/ijsem` and if this string occurs in a tag-element of the HTML, the text of the whole element should be returned.

Here is my code:

```
import scrapy

class BacteriaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'bacteria'
    allowed_domains = ['https://www.microbiologyresearch.org/content/journal/ijsem']
    start_urls = ['http://www.microbiologyresearch.org/content/journal/ijsem/']

    def parse(self, response):

        bacteria_species = ['Abditibacterium utsteinense',
                            'Abiotrophia defectiva',
                            'Abyssibacter profundi',
                            'Abyssicoccus albus',
                            'Abyssivirga alkaniphila',
                            'Acanthopleuribacter pedis',
                            'Acaricomes phytoseiuli',
                            'Acetanaerobacterium elongatum',
                            'Acetanaerobacterium sp.',
                            'Acetatifactor muris']

        for bacteria in bacteria_species:
            response.xpath("//*/text()[contains(., bacteria)]").getall()   # select the text of all nodes
        pass
```

Unfortunately it doeset work

Does anyone have a better idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is your xpath does not contain the proper format and you need to build it up dynamically like this:
def parse(self, response):
bacteria_species = ['prokaryotes',
'Malaciobacter']

```
    search_xpath = "//*/text()[contains(., {0})]"
    for bact in bacteria_species:
        searchfor = search_xpath.format('"' + bact + '"')
        print(searchfor)
        results =  response.xpath(searchfor).getall() 
        for item in results:
            yield{
            "bacteria" : bact,
            "results" : item
            }
```

I changed the bacteria_species to something that I saw multiples of in the web page and they were found. One thing to note is that xpath is case sensitive which could be a problem depending on the data

Comment: Thanks! This is what i searched for :)

Comment: Unfortunately, i now have the problem that my results are cut into pieces at the places where, for example, a span tag occurs in the desired element. So I want that for example the text content of my div-tag is completely scraped, even if a span-tag is included. is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Is what you posted is your exact code?

You have

```
start_urls = ['http://https://www.{...}']
```

which is invalid as it contains both `http://` and `https://`.

It should probably just be `https://www.{...}`.

Comment: Yes I had already corrected that, the code unfortunately still does not run as it should